# How to handle multiple api calls on a background job laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a background job firing api calls to google and facebook api's 
I know margin on failure for those api's its really slim, but due to the fact that my app depends on the data I get from those calls I want to make sure that my app doesnt get stuck when api call fails:

```
public function handle()
{
    try {

        $googleService = new GoogleClient;

        $data = $googleService->report()
            ->from('AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT')
            ->during('20170101', '20170126')
            ->select('
             Impressions, CampaignId, Clicks, Ctr,Cost, AverageCost, Interactions, Conversions, Status, Id')
            ->getObject();

        $this->transform->response($data->result);


        $client = new FacebookClient;

        $response = $client->insights()->select("impressions, ad_id, clicks,ctr, cpc,campaign_name ")->during('2013-01-01', '2018-01-31')->where(['accountid' => 'act_1222222'])->get();

        $this->transform->response($response);

    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }

}
```

I have done research on how to handle jobs when an api call fails, non of them helped.

***So my question is:***  What is the best way to handle the situation when an api call fails, In case one of them fails then I want to log the failure and keep the worker going ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel Queues](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues) to accomplish such tasks.

> Laravel queues provide a unified API across a variety of different
>   queue backends, such as Beanstalk, Amazon SQS, Redis, or even a
>   relational database. Queues allow you to defer the processing of a
>   time consuming task, such as sending an email, until a later time.
>   Deferring these time consuming tasks drastically speeds up web
>   requests to your application.

From Laravel's official site.

Comment: I searched the web and all I could find is same decent answers like this

Comment: So, what are you waiting for?

Comment: Can you please leave my question alone. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "proper" here?

Answer (score 0):

If your api call fails but your application depends on that response, you should try to retry the call again and again, until you get a proper response, you can probably use a timeout between requests too so you don't get the `Too Many Requests` response.

If your api call fails and your application doesn't depend on the response you can just use a logger and log the error in your file and either retry the call, or just skip it and continue.

But I agree with @Amit Merchant you should go with Laravel Queues

Answer (score 0):

Laravel has some interesting helper functions that you should look into. Of particular interest would be the [retry](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-retry) function. Just as it implies, it retries the execution of anything in the callback until either A) no exception is thrown, or B) the maximum threshold it reached.

Simply wrap your api call and specify a limit before handling a failed state.

Example from the docs:

```
return retry(5, function () {
   // Attempt 5 times while resting 100ms in between attempts...
}, 100);
```